# Unfreeze model Layer by Layer in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, layer

I'm working with a PyTorch model from [here](https://github.com/yitu-opensource/T2T-ViT) (T2T_ViT_7).

I'm trying to freeze all layers except the last (head) layer and train it on my dataset. I want to evaluate its performance, and then unfreeze layers one by one and train it each time and see how it performs.

To initially freeze all the layers and and just unfreeze the head layer, I used:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad_(False)

model.head.requires_grad_(True)
```

Now I want to start from the bottom, and start unfreezing layers one by one. How can I do this? Do I use model.modules() or maybe model.children()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If by *layers* you mean each block inside of `model.blocks`, then you can use [`nn.Module.children`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=children#torch.nn.Module.children) (// [`nn.Module.named_children`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=named_children#torch.nn.Module.named_children)). This will return all direct submodules, while the [`nn.Module.modules`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=modules#torch.nn.Module.modules) returns *all* submodules recursively.

Since `model.blocks` is a `nn.ModuleList`, you can slice the blocks to only select the last `n` layers. Something like that:

```
model.blocks[-n:].requires_grad_(False)
```